# iPhone only app rejected because it is a Universal binary

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, binary, itunes

I just had an iPhone only App rejected by iTunes connect because...

> In our review of your app, we found that it is a Universal app for both iPad and iPhone.  Because it is set as a universal binary, your app requires screenshots from iPhone and iPad.

The app had previously been a universal binary (never previously approved) and I had previously uploaded an iPad screenshot (just a place holder) to allow me to upload the binary.  (I had to upload then self reject a binary to test IAP.)

But as far as I can tell my app is a iphone only binary.  When I run it on the iOS iPad simulator it runs at iPhone resolution with the 2x button.  Yet when I upload this (I think) iPhone only binary to iTunes Connect it still asks for iPad screenshots.

In Xcode I have the following settings

> targets->Build Settings->targetted device family = iPhone.

and

> targets->Summary->Devices = iPhone.

And again it acts like an iPhone only app when I run it on the simulator.  Are there any other setting in XCode or in iTunes Connect that I need to set?  Thnx

---

EDIT
After my app was rejected I removed the placeholder iPad screenshots from iTunesConnect. (I had tried to do this several times before submitting the app, but was unable to.  I even wrote a developers note to the reviewer hoping they wouldn't spike my app for that reason.)  I also remove the ipad Default.png from my project.  One of the two of those actions fixed it.  I think because I had been testing the app as a universal it took a couple of submissions to for iTC to recognize that I was only uploading an iPhone version.  Either way, it now recognizes it as a iphone only and was approved.

Comment: "The app had previously been a universal binary" I wonder if that's the problem. Maybe once you've done that, you can never go back.

Comment: Double check *everything*. Make sure there are no iPad default launch images. Make sure there are no iPad size icons. Clean the slate! See if that helps.

Comment: I removed the iPad default image.  Also, there had been an iPad screenshot that I could not delete in iTunes connect prior to my last submission.  After getting the app rejected I was then able to delete it. (Why, who knows?)  With those two changes I have resubmitted my app.  Now the binary details list it as an iPhone/iPod touch device, so hopefully all is well and good.  If and win it gets accepted I'll mark this thread answered.

Comment: Yeah, removing the screenshots from iTunes Connect is a nightmare. At one point I actually emailed them and they refused to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my app was rejected I removed the placeholder iPad screenshots from iTunesConnect. (I had tried to do this several times before submitting the app, but was unable to. I even wrote a developers note to the reviewer hoping they wouldn't spike my app for that reason.) I also remove the ipad Default.png from my project. One of the two of those actions fixed it. I think because I had been testing the app as a universal it took a couple of submissions to for iTC to recognize that I was only uploading an iPhone version. Either way, it now recognizes it as a iphone only and was approved.

Answer (score 0):

just set build target devices In Sumary to iPhone...make a check in plist... also just load .xib files iPhone, make a clean in your project and rebuild.. Check if you are not loading some target

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't believe what you see in `targets->Summary`. Especially, if you ever changed to "Universial" and back to "iPhone".

Instead of `Summary` you should always check `targets->Info`.

Also if you change Icons, Orientations, etc. often there are leftovers which you only find in `Info`

Comment: I don't have any entries in ->Info re: universal vs iphone only.